# Is there a way to Query current user's password age (in days) in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, passwords, wmic

Specifically, I want to determine the age of the current password so that I can display it in a textbox in a windows form.

Perhaps there is something in the WMIC library that I haven't seen?

EDIT:

If you were to use `net user` + windows username (which i can pull easily) you get results that include the date in which the password was SET and when it EXPIRES. I want to pull that data.

Comment: I don’t really know how most Windows things relate, but Active Directory has a `Pwd-Last-Set` field: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679430(v=vs.85).aspx. Does that help in your case?

Comment: added more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
using (var userEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + '/' + Environment.UserName + ",user"))
{
    int secondsSinceLastChange = (int)userEntry.InvokeGet("PasswordAge");
    int daysSinceLastChange = secondsSinceLastChange / 60 / 60 / 24;

    Console.WriteLine("{0} days since your last password change.", daysSinceLastChange);
}
```

<sub>You might need to add the `System.DirectoryServices` reference.</sub>